# Write Unicode Text On Image In Python Pillow?

Tags: python, unicode, python-imaging-library

I Am Trying To Write Punjabi/Gurmukhi Text On Pillow Image It didn't Work Completely.
Here Is My Code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

#configuration
font_size=36
width=500
height=100
back_ground_color=(255,255,255)
font_size=36
font_color=(0,0,0)

# Unicode For "ਸ੍ਰੀ" is "\u0a38\u0a4d\u0a30\u0a40"
unicode_text = u"ਸ੍ਰੀ"

im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (width,height), back_ground_color )
draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw ( im )
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("raavi.ttf", font_size)
draw.text ( (10,10), unicode_text, font=unicode_font, fill=font_color )

im.save("text.jpg")
```

But Output Is This:
[image: Output Image]

Also When We Use `print(u"ਸ੍ਰੀ")` in Terminal Then It Will Return Same Text As Shown In Output Image. But When We Copy That Text From Terminal And Paste It SomeWhere Else Then Output Is Correct `ਸ੍ਰੀ`.

Comment: Perhaps you're not getting the font you asked for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found Solution.
This Is Because Python Is Rendering ਸ੍ਰੀ As Four Characters.
I Create A Package And TTF File For Display Words Correctly On Image And Pdf.

Check Out:- [pi7gurmukhi](https://pypi.org/project/pi7gurmukhi/)

[Correct Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POADO.jpg)

Comment: this looks a common problem for other Indian languages too. Can you help what needs to be done for other fonts/languages?